# Android studio - Add linked file to package

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to locate the linked by sourceset java file under the specific package.
for example we have the **SomeManager.java** file linked by sourceset in android studio it is located under the module node **somedemosdk** in project view.
 But we need that it will be located under the package node **some.package** because this package name defined in **SomeManager.java** does not recognized by android studio.
Please see the corresponding print screen:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the name `package` is allowed in the name of package?

Comment: instead of package (which is Java reserved name) use `packages` ;-)

Comment: it is just for the example
in real i have different package name

Answer (score 1):

`some.package` you need to rename you package to something like `some.mypackage`. because package is a reserved word in java.

Comment: it is just for the example in real i have different package name